# How to Display MySQL data as a checklist on HTML website?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

It's not a very complex problem but I've been stuck for the past few days and can't seem to figure it out. I have a database called "major_degrees" and I want to fetch all the majors from the table called "majors" in this database and then display it as a checklist on my website using PHP and HTML.

I believe the fault is somewhere in my while loop.. it is printing the data as text but I want it as a checklist so I can check off the options I want and save them.

Here is the PHP code I have so far:

```
<?php

    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbname = "major_degrees";
    $str='';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT degree_name FROM majors";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['degree_name'];
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        return $str;
    } 
    $conn->close();


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbname = "major_degrees";
    $str='';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT degree_name FROM majors";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $out = '';
    $cnt = 0;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $cnt++;
            $out .= '<input id="cb_' .$cnt. '" class="someclass" type="checkbox" />' .$row['degree_name']. '<br/>';
        }
        echo $out;
    } 
    $conn->close();


?>
```

---

When ready to get the checked values and send them to another page:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fm2umLm7/)</kbd>

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#myForm').submit(function(evnt){
  evnt.preventDefault(); //suppress submitting form (for demo)
  var chk = $('#myForm').serialize();
  alert(chk);
 });

}); //END document.ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="submitTo.php" method="get">
 <input id="cb_1" name="cb_1" type="checkbox" /> Test 1<br>
 <input id="cb_2" name="cb_2" type="checkbox" /> Test 2<br>
 <input id="cb_3" name="cb_3" type="checkbox" /> Test 3<br>
 <input id="cb_4" name="cb_4" type="checkbox" /> Test 4<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was very helpful. Any idea how I could limit checkbox selection on this? i.e. if I want the user to only select 3 out of 5 boxes how can I do that in php?

Comment: This question is answered, so I suggest that you choose a best answer and then repost as a new question with that new addition. Reason: (1) That's how SO works, and everyone benefits, and (2) Each time you ask a new question dozens of people read it and try to help. At this point only a couple will be following this comment thread. Very likely a new question will be answered within 5 mins. :)

Comment: Ahhh Okay, I'm a newbie to stackoverflow.. just made my account today :P Thanks for the info!

Comment: @MaydhaMn See new answer per comment request

Comment: @gibbersih Thanks! You updated solution works if I make the html table manually... but is there a way to make it work with just the initial php code ? i.e. the initial code I posted makes a checklist automatically out of the table in mysql.... i don't have to manually make it in html. Is there a way to limit those check boxes just in that php code without making additional check boxes in html? -- I am going to repost this as a new question so if you could answer there it would be a biggg help!! :)

Comment: You got it! I don't have the 15points yet so I'm unable to upvote your answer, but once I do I will definitely do that. I posted another question just now related to checklist limits with php.. please see if you can answer that :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. I had some extra time and put together a possible solution for you. Hope it helps.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Code To Play With**](https://jsfiddle.net/fm2umLm7/1/)</kbd>

```js
var boxcnt = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#myForm').submit(function(evnt){
  evnt.preventDefault(); //suppress submitting form (for demo)
  var chk = $('#myForm').serialize();
  alert(chk);
 });
  
    $('#myForm input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            //alert('checking');
            boxcnt++;
            if ( boxcnt > 3 ){
              alert('Max 3 checked');
              $(this).attr('checked', false);
              boxcnt--;
            }
        }else{
            //alert('unchecking');
            boxcnt--;
        }
    });

}); //END document.ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="submitTo.php" method="get">
 <input id="cb_1" name="cb_1" type="checkbox" /> Test 1<br>
 <input id="cb_2" name="cb_2" type="checkbox" /> Test 2<br>
 <input id="cb_3" name="cb_3" type="checkbox" /> Test 3<br>
 <input id="cb_4" name="cb_4" type="checkbox" /> Test 4<br>
 <input id="cb_5" name="cb_5" type="checkbox" /> Test 5<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must output the appropriate markup with your php code.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$row['degree_name']'> $row['degree_name']";
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

This must do the trick.

However, you'll be needing a form with a submit button which can be used to pass this data back to the server.

Comment: Thank you! You are right about the submit button, I forgot to include that.